# PHP cURL or https stream wrapper (openssl) most widely enabled

Tags: php, curl, https, openssl, portability

I'm trying to write portable php application. What I want is for this code to be working on as many shared hosting providers as possible with PHP >= 5.2

I need this code to operate with the Dropbox API so https support is needed. As I understand it I have 2 options - cURL and the https stream wrapper from the openssl extension.

My question is which one would you recommend that is enabled on most hosting providers.

Comment: Code Portability : Curl , Widely Enabled : https stream

Comment: @Baba can you explain to me in this case what is the difference between `code portability` and `widely enabled`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@stormbreaker

From what i understand

`Code Portability :  Means writing your program (code) in such a way that the same code works on different environments. You should be easy to understand , identify exceptions and maintain`

`Widely Enabled : Means as Having great extent or range in availability by default or supported by majority of service providers`

[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) supports more features in the same lib, cleaner , multiple processing etc.

`https stream wrapper` is more widely available can be very tricky depending when you move form platform to platform depending on the application

Comment: I have a working class that handles the dropbox api by using the `https stream wrapper`. What bugs me is that on my windows development machine I had to enable the `openssl` extension to get the `https wrapper` working while my hosting provider has both `curl` and `openssl` enabled. So in your opinion should I rewrite the code using `curl` if I want to target a wider range of service providers?

Comment: You would need to enable both `CURL` and `https wrapper` on some systems depending on the setup. But they are other things that affects `https wrapper` eg. `Runtime Configuration : allow_url_fopen` this does not affect `CURL`

Comment: Thanks, I decided I'm going to use `CURL` for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) in the PHP Manual, the `cURL` functions were added "in PHP 4.0.2."

Due to that, I think you will be fine with >=5.2 servers. Moreover, cURL is way better than the PHP Stream functions. So, stick with cURL!